# JavaScript getting variable outside xhr function using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get the variable that was initialized before the constructor. For example

```
title: String = 'hello'
```

To get that from a function( this works)

```
functionname () {
    //this will work
    console.log(this.title)
}
```

But from my original code, i am trying to get it from XHR's onload function and not able to access it.

```
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {
  description: string;
  title: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  upload() {
    this.makeFileRequest("/api/upload_video", []).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var formData: any = new FormData();
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.responseType = 'text';

      xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
          //trying to get this.title
          console.log(this.title)
        }
      };
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
  }
}
```

error

```
'Error' message: 'Property 'title' does not exist on type XMLHttpRequestEventTarget'.'
```

What am I missing to access this.title

Comment: `this` refer to the XHR. Cache `this` of the class. Add `var _this = this;` in the promise above `onload` callback and use `_this.title` in the callback.

Comment: Thanks, this works. please create it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work

```
 makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var formData: any = new FormData();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var that = this;

  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'text';

  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
      //trying to get this.title
      console.log(that.title)
    }
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
 });
}
}
```